# switch case или вызов метода в объекте javascript что лучше?

Tags: javascript

```
var key = 'сюда приходит какое то значение, возможно с помощью цикла';
switch(key){
      case 'muteOn':
          var value = v;
          log('mute ON');
          break;
}
```

или

```
var object = {
    muteOn: function(v){
       log('mute ON');
    }
}

object[key](v);
```

Давайте представим что "кейсов" около 100 или даже 1000 записей. Что будет работать быстрее? Мне почему то кажется, что обратиться к методу объекта будет быстрее чем через switch case

Comment: Слишком мало кода.

Comment: Между switch и объектом при 1000 свойств лучше объект, т.к. создание большого количества свойств в объекте проще автоматизировать, в то время как со switch придется повозиться.